# Multiple audio are played simultaneously at multiple image clicks

Tags: javascript

I have 5 images & 5 different audios for each of the image. When I click on the first image then the first audio plays & when the second image is clicked then the second audio is played along with the first one. I want to play only the single audio assigned to the image when the image is clicked.

```js
<a onclick="myAudioFunction('a');">    
   <img src="first.jpg" height="500px" width="500px" >    
</a>    
<a onclick="myAudioFunction('b');">    
   <img src="second.jpg" height="500px" width="500px">    
</a>    
<script>
  var aAudio = new Audio('audio1.mp3');
  var bAudio = new Audio('audio2.mp3');
function myAudioFunction(letter) {
                        if(letter == 'a') 
                        {
                            aAudio.play();
                        }
                        else if(letter == 'b')
                        {
                            bAudio.play();
                        }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it like this?

```
    <script>
function myAudioFunction(letter) {
  if(letter == 'a') 
                        {
                            var aAudio = new Audio('audio1.mp3');
                            aAudio.play();
                        }
                        else if(letter == 'b')
                        {
                            var bAudio = new Audio('audio2.mp3');
                            bAudio.play();
                        }
}
</script>
```